# How to extract a substring using a regular expression?

Tags: regex, sparql

I do encounter strings in a query like this

```
o = 'some interesting {foo123:bar_675:get_me.xyz} string'
```

and I want to extract the part after the last colon from the part inside the curly brackets, so in this case `get_me.xyz`.

I know that the regex `\{.*:(.*)\}` would work (tested in Python):

```
import re

o = 'some interesting {foo123:bar_675:get_me.xyz} string'
re.findall('\{.*:(.*)\}', o)
```

will return

```
['get_me.xyz']
```

How could I use this regex now in a query?

I tried

```
SELECT (regex(?o, "\{.*:(.*)\}") as ?substring) ?o  
WHERE { 
  ?s ?p ?o .   
}
```

But that always throws an error

```
Parse error on line 6:
...SELECT (regex(?o, "\{.*:(.*)\}") as ?
---------------------^
Expecting 'IRIREF', 'PNAME_NS', 'VAR', '(', 'INTEGER', '!', '-', 'FUNC_ARITY0', 'FUNC_ARITY1', 'FUNC_ARITY2', 'IF', 'BOUND', 'BNODE', 'EXISTS', 'COUNT', 'FUNC_AGGREGATE', 'GROUP_CONCAT', 'DECIMAL', 'DOUBLE', 'true', 'false', 'STRING_LITERAL1', 'STRING_LITERAL2', 'STRING_LITERAL_LONG1', 'STRING_LITERAL_LONG2', 'INTEGER_POSITIVE', 'DECIMAL_POSITIVE', 'DOUBLE_POSITIVE', 'INTEGER_NEGATIVE', 'DECIMAL_NEGATIVE', 'DOUBLE_NEGATIVE', 'PNAME_LN', '+', 'NOT', 'CONCAT', 'COALESCE', 'SUBSTR', 'REGEX', 'REPLACE', got 'INVALID'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

REGEX is a filter test, REPLACE is the extraction operation.

```
SELECT *
WHERE { 
  ?s ?p ?o .   
  FILTER REGEX(?o, "\\{.*:(.*)\\}")
}
```

which tests `?o`, and does not extract the `()` part.

Note the double `\\`.

To extract use BIND-REPLACE.

```
SELECT * {
  ?s ?p ?o .   
  BIND(REPLACE(?o, "^.*\\{.*:(.*)\\}.*$", "$1") AS ?substring)
}
```

In the general case, you may need `str(?o)` instead of `?o` in functions.

Comment: That almost works. It now replaces the curly brackets part by the desired substring, it seems. So from my example above, it would return: `'some interesting get_me.xyz string'`. But I would like to have only the `get_me.xyz` part. Any ideas?

Comment: @Cleb, `replace(?o, '^.*\\{.*:(.*)\\}.*$', "$1")`? See also https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#regex-syntax. You could also use `STRBEFORE` + `STRAFTER`.

Comment: @StanislavKralin: Great, that does the trick, indeed. Thanks a lot!